# Recently recieved about 15 attacks and wanted an expert to explain what each was trying to do

Tags: .net, security, asp.net-mvc-2, iis-7

What I'm looking for is the following:

1. What are the attacks below trying to do?
2. Since an exception was thrown did the attack fail?
3. Are there any possible attacks that could have been thrown similar to these that may have went through.
4. Any links that lead to non-hacker friendly information so I can get up to speed on the evils of our world.

Answers will be given for partial answer since this is a long post.  If I posted incorrectly or should have posted elsewhere let me know and I will correct.  If you need more information please let me know also.  Thanks in advance.

Site background ASP.NET 4.0, MVC 2.0, LLBLGEN DataAccess Layer, Ninject as you can tell below, MS SQL 2008.

1. Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).
   Request URL: http://www.domain.com/)&&a.endsWith(
2. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name
   Request URL: http://www.domain.com/);if(a.NumberGroupSeparator!==n)c=c.split(n).join(
3. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name ',b=a.indexOf('.
   Request URL: http://www.domain.com/,b=a.indexOf(
4. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 
   Request URL: http://www.domain.com/Sys.NotImplementedException
5. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name
   Request URL: http://www.domain.com/,a),d=e.indexOf(
6. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 
   Request URL: http://www.domain.com/,String.format(Sys.Res.enumInvalidValue,c.split(
7. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name
   Request URL: http://www.domain.com/Sys.ParameterCountException
8. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 
   Request URL: http://www.domain.com/,Sys.EventArgs);Type.registerNamespace(
9. Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).
   Request URL: http://www.domain.com/);if(a&&a.tagName.toUpperCase()===
10. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name
    Request URL: http://www.domain.com/Sys.InvalidOperationException
11. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Sys.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'.
    Request URL: http://www.domain.com/Sys.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
12. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name
    Request URL: http://www.domain.com/action
13. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name
    Request URL: http://www.domain.com/Sys.FormatException
14. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 
    Request URL: http://www.domain.com/)a.value=
15. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name
    Request URL: class=true;Number._typeName=">http://www.domain.com/;Date._*class=true;Number.*_typeName=
16. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name
    Request URL: http://www.domain.com/Sys.ArgumentNullException
17. Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).
    Request URL: http://www.domain.com/&&a.display!==
18. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 
    Request URL: http://www.domain.com/Sys.ArgumentTypeException
19. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name
    Request URL: http://www.domain.com/;a.style.display=
20. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name
    Request URL: http://www.domain.com/).join(
21. Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).
    Request URL: http://www.domain.com/&&(b.position===
22. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name
    Request URL: class=true;RegExp._typeName=">http://www.domain.com/;Number._*class=true;RegExp.*_typeName=
23. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name Request URL: http://www.domain.com/);a.append(b.getTime());a.append(
24. Exception message: The IControllerFactory 'Ninject.Web.Mvc.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name
    Request URL: http://www.domain.com/hcp/html/mTag.js

Comment: IMHO, this does not look like attacks, but more like a bug somewhere. Each Exception seems to correspond with a line portion of some C# stack text that was appended to "http://www.domain.com/". Attacks don't look like that.

Comment: @Simon Mourier: checking against the uri strings in the server request log should clear that up.  If there's nothing matching, this means this 'ninject' product is defective or not properly configured.

Comment: These were all sent with in 30 seconds of each other from the same ip address.  That is why I was assuming this was an attempt to get something.  We have very little traffic right now and at 1am I'm the only traffic on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What are the attacks below trying to do?

They're trying to execute some code on your server by giving a bad URL and hoping you'd fall for it.

> Since an exception was thrown did the attack fail?

Yes.

> Are there any possible attacks that could have been thrown similar to these that may have went through.

Yes. If they were successful you probably wouldn't have gotten an exception.

> Any links that lead to non-hacker friendly information so I can get up to speed on the evils of our world.

Read up on injection in general. As a rule, don't trust strings from the user to be syntactically valid - the canonical example is inserting an input string into a SQL query without checking the input, which can be `"; DROP TABLE users;` I'm not familiar enough with ASP.Net to answer exactly, but it seems like somewhere the URL is executed? That doesn't make sense, so listen to somebody else on that front.

Comment: Any more detail on what any of the attacks do in general?  For instance number 19 what would ;a.style.display= accomplish?

Comment: well, display=none could add an invisible link (for shady SEO purposes, for example). Or it could be used to simply test if the injection worked, and do so in a hard-to-detect way.